# How can I put the iterable numbers into a new column each iteration?

Tags: r

```
# Creating an empty dataframe
result_df <- data.frame()

# Iterating over the numbers 1 to 3
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Create a new column and populate it with values of i
  result_df[, paste0("Column", i)] <- i
}
```

I expect to have the following populated dataframe:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1       1       2       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is vectorized and this can be done without loops at all.
Note that `nums <- seq_len(3)` is an alternative way of creating the vector `nums`.

```r
nums <- 1:3
row <- setNames(nums, paste0("Column", nums))
as.data.frame(t(row))
#>   Column1 Column2 Column3
#> 1       1       2       3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>